# Typescript: check for {}

Tags: typescript

How can I check in TypeScript/JavaScript if an element is {} (here the 1st)?

```
let lst : any [] = [{}, {name: 'abc'}];
```

I tried these but none of them worked.

```
if (lst [0] == {})

if (lst [0].toString () == "{}")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try** `Object.keys(obj).length == 0`

With your code:

```js
let lst = [{}, {name: 'abc'}];

if (Object.keys(lst[0]).length == 0) {
  console.log("Hey this is empty! length:", Object.keys(lst[0]).length)
  console.log("Other length: ", Object.keys(lst[1]).length)
}
```

Source: [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)